# Firefox Play() function - sound integration plugin

Tags: audio, firefox, plugins

I have recently accessed a webpage with sound built into it. The javascript code is supposed to play a sound when I click the button (I guess it's Play() function):

```
<embed enablejavascript="true" id="sound" autostart="true" src="">
<input type="button" onclick="get_element('sound').Play();">
```

However, when I click the button, no sound is played. Firefox displays small black bar on the top saying that "Additional plugins are required to display all the media on this page". There is button which offers me installation of that plugins but when I click it, no plugins are found.

I guess the embed element is supposed to contain the media when the plugin is installed.

Which plugins do I need to install to get the sound on the webpage? Is there any solution accessible via package manager? Can one easily find the solution if "No suitable plugins were found"?

- At MS Windows 7, the page says it needs "quicktime plugin". And yes, I have ubuntu-restricted-extras installed. I have tried to install various plugins, none works.

Comment: any webpage or one in particular - can you add a link to your question?

Comment: Unfortunately the page is in the authorized part of system, I can't send any working link.

Comment: do you know what the media type is?  have you installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras` for the extra media codecs?

Comment: At MS Windows 7, the page says it needs "quicktime plugin". And yes, I have `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed. I have tried to install various plugins, none works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a Terminal (Dash->Terminal) window:

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin ubuntu-restricted-extras ubuntu-desktop totem-mozilla
```

See if that helps, and if not, upgrade Firefox with this link: http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/firefox-and-thunderbird-5-6-7-and-8/

Comment: This didn't work. However, I give you the bounty for your effort. Thanks anyway.